# Check a checkbox on select of an option

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a very basic example. Based on the JSON, I need to select the correct value on the select and check/not check the checkbox.

I'm using ng-model but it's not working. Can you help me?

```js
var vm = this;


vm.ticket = {"FUTURE_CALL":1,"TICKET_PRIORITY_DESCRIPTION":"Normal"}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<select id="priority-select" uib-tooltip="Select a Priority" ng-model="vm.ticket.TICKET_PRIORITY_CODE" required="" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" style="">
  <option value="" disabled="">--- Please select a priority ---</option>
  <!-- not selected / blank option -->
  <!-- ngRepeat: priority in vm.priorities -->
  <option ng-repeat="priority in vm.priorities" value="L" class="ng-binding ng-scope" style="">
    Low
  </option>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: priority in vm.priorities -->
  <option ng-repeat="priority in vm.priorities" value="N" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
    Normal
  </option>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: priority in vm.priorities -->
  <option ng-repeat="priority in vm.priorities" value="H" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
    High
  </option>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: priority in vm.priorities -->
  <option ng-repeat="priority in vm.priorities" value="U" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
    Unknown
  </option>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: priority in vm.priorities -->
</select>


<input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.ticket.FUTURE_CALL" />
```

Comment: Is there a concrete issue? What did you try already?

Comment: You have to give more of your code. There seems to be lots of issues with what you've got here. For example vm.ticket should be $scope.vm.ticket and you only need one ng-repeat to loop through every priority in vm.priorities

Comment: why is there a ng-repeat for each of your `option` tag ?

Comment: there is no no repeat. I have that html and I need to select an option and check a checkbox based on the vm.ticket , it's as simple as that

Comment: can you provide a plunkr for this ? it may not be working, but should explain your requirement